# How to show query results in html options box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JavaScript.

This query returns my results correctly, I know want to make those results via the options box on the html page. I thought I could just pass "friends" into the second code block to achieve this, but it doesn't work. Do I need to save the results first, before using them in the (2) code block?

1.......

```
query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                var friends = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    friends.push({
                        username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                        userId: results[i].get('toUser').id

                    });
                }
```

---

2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = (friends);
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
    });
```

---

3 HTML

```
 <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should do the operations on *friends* after success call back, not  on document ready.

Comment: @Mldun Krishna THanks, if you make the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezvnp/122/) ,try this

In 1st Part

```
   friends.push({
            "username" : "+results[i].get('toUser').get('username')+",
            "userId" : "+results[i].get('toUser').id+"

     });
```

In 2 Part

```
  var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
  $.each(friends[0],function(i,v){

      var opt = v;
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
  })
```

problem is `friends.push({ Json Object });`.

and `var option= (friends)` you was stroe array object in options.but you need to iteatre it and get back json value.

Comment: Perfect, awarded the answer based on the quality of response.

Answer (score 1):

Do the operations on the data returned by the query in the success callback of the query. At the time of `$(document).ready()`, the data wont be available :)

Answer (score 1):

The code here is asynchrone, which means JS calls the remote server for your query and continue to executes until it gets a response. Once it gets it, it calls your callback function with the results. Thus, you can’t just use the results after your query, because you don’t have the response yet. You have to ensure you use them *after* you get the response, which is why you have to write your code in the callback (or in another function you’ll call in the callback).

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/z32NG/):

HTML:

```
<p id="results1"></p>
<p id="results2"></p>
```

JS:

```
var results = [],
    query = JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"});

$.post('/echo/json/', {json: query}, function(data) {
    results.push(data.foo);
    $('#results2').text('in callback: ' + results.join(''));
});
$('#results1').text('after async call: ' + results.join(''));
```

If you run it, you should see that just after the `$.post` call, `results` is still empty, because the previous call is done asynchronously. When the callback is executed, `results` contains `"bar"` as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I marked this up, but the other answer is slightly more relevant to parse.com. Many thanks